# Jersey remote ip address not working correctly

Tags: java, rest, heroku, jersey-2.0

I am trying to retrieve the IP address which makes the call to a REST call.

The code I have is:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.json.JSONObject;

@Path("/api")
public class Endpoints {

    @GET
    @Path("/whoami")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String testHeaders(@Context final HttpServletRequest request){

        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("remoteaddr", request.getRemoteAddr());

        return json.toString(4);
    }

}
```

the application is deployed on heroku [here](https://rj93-request-header-parser.herokuapp.com/api/whoami). When you make the call to the api it returns the ip is: `10.155.0.152`, how ever when I google it it says my IP address is something different. Is there any way to return the actual IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku sets a number of [request headers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#heroku-headers) that contain this kind of information. In your case, you'll want:

```
request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
```

This will return the originating IP address of the client connecting to the Heroku router.

The IP address you are getting from `request.getRemoteAddr()` is probably the Heroku router.